# Warning: "format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)" in C

Tags: c, file, input

I am writing a file with a variable fcontents to enter the contents of a file that are wanted. I keep getting the warning "format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)" and I don't know what that means.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  
  char fname[20];

  char fcontents[20];
  
  printf("Enter a file name: ");
  scanf("%s", fname);
  printf("Enter file contents: ");
  scanf("%s", fcontents);
  
  FILE * fpointer = fopen(fname,"w");
    
  fprintf(fpointer, fcontents);
    
  fclose(fpointer);

  printf("FILE: %s successfully created", fname);

}
```

Comment: It is the difference between `printf("%s", "A string")` and `printf("A string")`.

Comment: Because you get the string to be printed from user input, a malicious user could put conversion specifications in there which at a minimum may crash your program (and thus constitute a "denial of service" attack), e.g. `const char *s = "%s"; printf(s)`.

Comment: In `fprintf(fpointer, fcontents);` suppose the user input had included a format specifier? There is no matching argument.

Comment: If you want to know what might go wrong, take a look at [xkcd-Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) That does not exactly match for `printf` but you should get the idea...

Comment: Not causing your error but `scanf("%s", fname);` should be changed to contain a length limit: `scanf("%19s", fname);` Same for all calls to `scanf` to read a string. You should also check return value of `scanf` and all other IO functions like `fopen` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  
  char fname[20];

  char fcontents[20];
  
  printf("Enter a file name: \nEnter file contents:");
  
  scanf("%s %s", fname, fcontents);
  
  FILE * fpointer = fopen(fname,"w");
    
  fprintf(fpointer, "%s", fcontents);
    
  fclose(fpointer);

  printf("FILE: %s successfully created", fname);

}
```

Note that you can also use `fputs` instead of `fprintf` in this case.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  
  char fname[20];

  char fcontents[20];
  
  printf("Enter a file name: \nEnter file contents:");
  
  scanf("%s %s", fname, fcontents);
  
  FILE * fpointer = fopen(fname,"w");
    
  fputs(fcontents, fpointer);
    
  fclose(fpointer);

  printf("FILE: %s successfully created", fname);

}
```

Comment: Your wish to help is appreciated. Nevertheless, answers that do not contain any explanation why something needs to be changed are considered low quality. You might edit your answer to provide an explanation.